# Intersection of $\delta$-neighborhoods of lines

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, arc-length

I think I know how to prove this for inner product spaces, but not how to prove it for the more general normed spaces (assuming it's true).

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two distinct lines through the origin in a real normed vector space. Let $B_\delta(P)$ and $B_\delta(Q)$ be the set of points whose distance to $P$ or $Q$ is less than $\delta$. Similarly, $B_\epsilon(\{0\})$ is a closed ball of radius $\epsilon$ around the origin.

For any $\epsilon$, is there a $\delta$ such that:
$$B_\delta(P)\cap B_\delta(Q)\subseteq B_\epsilon(\{0\})?$$

This came up when I was trying to justify some intuition on the formal definition of the arc-length of a curve.

Comment: Done ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We shall proceed by contradiction.

Suppose that a certain $\epsilon$ exists, such that $B_\delta(P)\cap B_\delta(Q)\not\subseteq B_\epsilon(\{0\})$ for any positive $\delta$.

This means that for every $\delta>0$ we can find a point $x$ such that $||x||>\epsilon$ and $d(x,P),(x,Q)<\delta$.

This implies that we can find a point $p\in P$ and $q\in Q$ such that $d(x,p)<2\delta$ and $d(x,q)<2\delta$. In turn, this implies again by the triangle inequality that $d(p,q)<4\delta$.

Again, by the triangle inequality we must have $||p||, ||q|| \geq \epsilon-\delta$

Taking any $\delta \leq \epsilon/2$ we conclude we can always find $p\in P$, $q\in Q$ such that $||p-q||<\delta$ and $||p||,||q||\geq \epsilon/2$.

Now, let $p_0$ and $q_0$ be two points in $P$ and $Q$ respectively with norm $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Our previous result can be expressed as follows:

For every $\delta>0$ we can find reals $x,y$ such that $|x|,|y|\geq 1$ and $||xp-yq||<\delta$.

The set $A=\{xp_0+yq_0 | |x|\geq 1, |y|\geq 1\}$ is closed, as it is a closed subset of a finite dimensional subspace of a vector space.

Moreover, when we intersect it with the ball $B_{\epsilon}(\{0\})$ we obtain a compact set. And therefore it contains a vector of minimum norm, a contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure how paragraphs 2 and 3 follow.

Comment: doesn't paragraph $2$ follow directly from the fact that if you can find a point $x$ arbitrarily close to both $P$ and $Q$ then you can find a point in $P$ that is really closed to $x$ and a point in $Q$ really close to $x$?

Comment: I don't see how the points in $P$ and $Q$ have to be outside the $\epsilon$-ball, but they do have to be outside the $\epsilon/2$-ball.

Comment: well yeah, we have to take a couple of different epsilons to make it  work fine. But I think paragraph $3$ is reachable making the appropriate tweaks.

Comment: Oh, I see how the second paragraph works. Not sure how the third follows, though.

Comment: ok, so we can find vectors of the form $\lambda v + \kappa w$ with norm as small as possible, and with $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ both not too small. we can just add the restriction that $\lambda+ \kappa=1$, and we should still be able to make the norm as small as needed (by linearity of the norm).

Comment: Where you first introduce $x$ and $y$, you say $|x|,|y|\ge1$, but in the last paragraph, you look at the subset of $\Bbb R^2$ defined by $|x|,|y|\le1$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger oh yeah, my bad. It should be ok now.